# Create a background behind image with full width?

Tags: html, css, image, append, width

I have a small challenge. I have a wordpress theme with fixed width for text. i would like to add images but add a background to each image which is full width. Is that possible?

I had the idea to make a wrapper. position it absolute left 0 and make the image center.

Or is there a way to make some classes ignore a rule or how i could make an exception?

Comment: i think i found a way: .full-width {
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  margin-left: -50vw;
  margin-right: -50vw;
}

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about WordPress themes but if it's CSS just do:

```css
body: {
  background-image: url("your url or file path here")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code may fix your issue

```
.yourselecter {
   background-image: url("your image url");
   background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

if the image is stretch use this property

```
.yourselecter {
   background-size: cover;
}
```